# error when use multithreading and mysqldb

Tags: python

getting error when multithreader program access data .

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:

ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

Exception in thread Thread-3:

ProgrammingError: execute() first
```

Answer (score 14):

According to [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), data access modules have a module level constant `threadsafety`:

> Integer constant stating the level of thread safety the interface
>   supports. Possible values are:
>
> 0     Threads may not share the module. 
>     1     Threads may share the module, but not connections.
>     2     Threads may share the module and connections. 
>   3     Threads may share the module, connections and
>           cursors.
>
> Sharing in the above context means that two threads may use a resource
>   without wrapping it using a mutex semaphore to implement resource
>   locking. Note that you cannot always make external resources thread
>   safe by managing access using a mutex: the resource may rely on global
>   variables or other external sources that are beyond your control.

According to [MySQLdb User's Guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes), the module supports level 1.

> The MySQL protocol can not handle multiple threads using the same
>   connection at once. Some earlier versions of MySQLdb utilized locking
>   to achieve a threadsafety of 2. While this is not terribly hard to
>   accomplish using the standard Cursor class (which uses
>   mysql_store_result()), it is complicated by SSCursor (which uses
>   mysql_use_result(); with the latter you must ensure all the rows have
>   been read before another query can be executed. It is further
>   complicated by the addition of transactions, since transactions start
>   when a cursor execute a query, but end when COMMIT or ROLLBACK is
>   executed by the Connection object. Two threads simply cannot share a
>   connection while a transaction is in progress, in addition to not
>   being able to share it during query execution. This excessively
>   complicated the code to the point where it just isn't worth it.
>
> The general upshot of this is: Don't share connections between
>   threads. It's really not worth your effort or mine, and in the end,
>   will probably hurt performance, since the MySQL server runs a separate
>   thread for each connection. You can certainly do things like cache
>   connections in a pool, and give those connections to one thread at a
>   time. If you let two threads use a connection simultaneously, the
>   MySQL client library will probably upchuck and die. You have been
>   warned.

Comment: But then if i dont share the objects and use singleton then it gives error ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

Comment: @GaneshGhalame You need multiple connection objects, not a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

here is detail about the error:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html.

Mysqldb's manual suggest these:

Don't share connections between threads. It's really not worth your effort or mine, and in the end, will probably hurt performance, since the MySQL server runs a separate thread for each connection. You can certainly do things like cache connections in a pool, and give those connections to one thread at a time. If you let two threads use a connection simultaneously, the MySQL client library will probably upchuck and die. You have been warned.

For threaded applications, try using a connection pool. This can be done using the Pool module

See more information search keyword threadsafety on [MySQLdb manual](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html),

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your few informations, I can only guess.

Probably you access the database from several threads without locking. That's bad.

You should hold a lock to a `threading.Lock()` or `threading.RLock()` while accessing your DB. This prevents several threads from interfering with other thread's actions.

Comment: But then if i dont share the objects and use singleton then it gives error ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"