# Python Multithreading and databases request?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm building a script that use Multithreading.Pool for calling multiple item at once, and I have an odd result.

As a starter, here's my (simplified) code, but tested and working (or failing :p) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import MySQLdb
import time
import multiprocessing
import sys
import logging

TIMEOUT = 2500 # ms, 2,5 seconds
MAX_TIMEOUT = 120000 # ms, 2 minutes

DB_PARAMS = {
    'user': 'root',
    'passwd': '******',
    'db': 'my_db'
}

class CheckState:
    def __call__(self, row):
        print "Calling for %s" % (row[0], )

        # Retrieving n-1 instance
        entry_id = row[0]
        print entry_id
        last_log = database.find_unique("SELECT status FROM entry_logs WHERE entry_id = %s ORDER BY occured DESC LIMIT 1;", (entry_id, ))
        print entry_id, last_log


class DatabaseBridge:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cnx = MySQLdb.connect (**kwargs)
        self.cnx.autocommit(True)
        self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor()

    def query_all(self, query, *args):
        self.cursor.execute(query, *args)
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    def find_unique(self, query, *args):
        rows = self.query_all(query, *args);
        if len(rows) == 1:
            return rows[0]

        return None

    def execute(self, query, params):
        self.cursor.execute(query, params)
        return self.cursor.rowcount

    def close(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.cnx.close()

database = DatabaseBridge(**DB_PARAMS)


def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

    try:
        logging.info("===================================")
        rows = database.query_all("SELECT id FROM entries WHERE is_disabled = 0 AND removed IS NULL AND IFNULL(address, '') != '';")

        if len(rows) > 0:
            pool_timeout = len(rows) * TIMEOUT
            if pool_timeout > MAX_TIMEOUT:
                pool_timeout = MAX_TIMEOUT

            result = pool.map_async(CheckState(), rows)

            pool.close()
            pool.join()

            logging.info("Running for %d seconds max", float(pool_timeout)/1000)
            result.get(timeout=float(pool_timeout)/1000) # Maximum Timeout allowed for security reasons !

        end_time = time.time() - start_time
        logging.info("Took approx %.2f seconds to run.", end_time)

        database.close()
        pool.terminate()

        return 0
    except Exception, err:
        end_time = time.time() - start_time

        print "An error occured with the script"
        print "Took approx %.2f seconds to run." % (end_time, )

        logging.error("Took approx %.2f seconds to run.", end_time)
        logging.exception("Script failed")

        pool.terminate()
        database.close()

        return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

In my Database, I have 10 rows in the table entries, and in the table entry_logs, I have n*entries rows in it.

Status in entry_logs can either be OK, DOWN or INVALID.

In my database, only entry_id 5 and 10 have DOWN or INVALID, all the 8 others always have status OK

Now when I run my script, I got this :

```
Calling for 1
1
Calling for 2
2
Calling for 3
3
Calling for 4
4
1 ('OK',)
Calling for 6
6
Calling for 7
7
Calling for 5
5
6 ('OK',)
Calling for 8
8
8 ('OK',)
Calling for 9
9
9 ('OK',)
Calling for 10
10
10 ('OK',)
5 ('OK',)
4 ('INVALID',)
3 ('OK',)
7 ('OK',)
```

The keys here are :

```
5 ('OK',)
10 ('OK',)
4 ('INVALID',)
```

It's impossible, **5 and 10 should return INVALID, 4 should return OK**

So I'm guessing my threads are messing with the `DatabaseBridge` class and returned data are crossed between the Threads and not returned at the correct one, but then, how can I fix it ?

Bonus point: Some times (not every times), my script just hangs, and never returns. Despite the fact that I force a `timeout` on the `get()` method, I have to kill the main processus, and one child (probably the one that is hanged). Do you have an idea about why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a long hour of heavy searching, I think I've found the reason, but the solution (or an alternative one) will have to be implemented.

In fact, the problem is greatly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9173737/330867) :

> MySQLdb User's Guide, the module supports level 1. ("Threads may share the module, but not connections.").

In short : I shouldn't use the same connection for my queries because it's not guarantee that the result will be returned for the correct thread. And it's exactly what I'm experiencing.

Now I have two options :

1 - Either work with a Mysql Pool
 2 - Rewrite the code to Pool only what's taking long to compute, not the whole work.

I think I'll go for the second one, more simpler ;)