# Python Connection to MariaDB server closes about every 24 hours

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I'm creating a product for my company to keep track of items with RFID tags attached, they swipe at the kiosk, it's logged in the database, simple.

The database is actually hosted on the kiosk (not best practice, I know), and the main program running on the kiosk is a python frontend with GuiZero. The kiosk runs Raspbian Desktop off of a Raspberry Pi.

Everything works well, but (approximately) 24 hours after the program launches, it acts like normal, until a database query is sent to the server. The python-mariadb-connector responds with: `2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '127.0.0.1:3306', system error: 32 Broken pipe`, I've been troubleshooting this for about a month now and I'm now sure what could fix it.

I've tried simply renewing the connection from within the python frontend whenever this happens, but that doesn't work either. The only thing that fixes the issue, is restarting the program, which users can't be trusted with figuring out how to do.

One thing to note is that everything works **perfectly until** that ~24 hour mark hits.

Any help?

**Dependencies:**

```
Python 3.7
(pip) mysql-connector v2.2.9
MariaDB: 10.3.17-MariaDB-0+deb10ul Raspbian 10
Raspbian GNU/Linux v10
```

Timeout Variables

```
MariaDB [locker]> show variables like "%timeout";
+---------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                         | Value |
+---------------------------------------+-------+
| connect_timeout                       | 10    |
| delayed_insert_timeout                | 300   |
| idle_readonly_transaction_timeout     | 0     |
| idle_transaction_timeout              | 0     |
| idle_write_transaction_timeout        | 0     |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout           | 1     |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout              | 50    |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout            | OFF   |
| interactive_timeout                   | 28800 |
| lock_wait_timeout                     | 86400 |
| net_read_timeout                      | 30    |
| net_write_timeout                     | 60    |
| rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout          | 10000 |
| rpl_semi_sync_slave_kill_conn_timeout | 5     |
| slave_net_timeout                     | 60    |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout              | 60    |
| wait_timeout                          | 28800 |
+---------------------------------------+-------+
```

Here's the code, line 166 is where the error is handled. (Not that my handling does anything)
Ctrl+F for "aghiulg" to get to that line.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
from datetime import datetime
from sys import exit

# Classes
class User:
    def __init__ (self, rfid, name):
        self.name = name
        self.rfid = rfid

class Key:
    def __init__ (self, rfid, kid, prop, loc):
        self.rfid = rfid
        self.kid = kid
        self.prop = prop.split("/")
        self.loc = loc

    def toString (self):
        return "[{}] {}".format(self.kid, "/".join(self.prop[:3]))

# Slack
import slack

slackBotToken = "OBFUSCATEDFORSTACKOVERFLOW"
slackClient = slack.WebClient(slackBotToken)
slackID = None

def getTimeString ():
    now = datetime.now()
    return now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

def log (s):
    time = getTimeString()

    # stdout
    print("[{}] {}".format(time, s))


    # slack
    slackErr = False
    try:
        slackClient.chat_postMessage(channel = "#keys", text = s)
    except concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError:
        slackErr = True

    # file
    with open("/home/pi/key-locker/log.txt", "a+") as f:
        f.write("[{}] {}\n".format(time, s))
        if slackErr:
            f.write("Couldn't write that to Slack, oops.")

def xlog (s):
    try:
        slackClient.chat_postMessage(channel = "OBFUSCATED", text = s)
        return True
    except concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError:
        return False

# guizero
from guizero import App, Text, TextBox, info

app = App(title = "Key Locker")
app.tk.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
REFOCUS_TIMER = 500
USER_TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000

# MariaDB
import mysql.connector as mariadb

def connectDB ():
    xlog("Reconnecting to database...")
    return mariadb.connect(user="OBFUSCATED", password="OBFUSCATED", database="OBFUSCATED")

# mdb = mariadb.connect(user="OBFUSCATED", password="OBFUSCATED", database="OBFUSCATED")
mdb = connectDB()
cursor = mdb.cursor(buffered = True)

def focusUIN (uin = None):
    if uin:
        uin.focus()

def onTextBoxKey (e, f = None):
    global uidBox, kidBox, bigText, underText, currentUser, currentKey, escapeKeys

    if len(e.key) == 0:
        return

    if f == uidBox and ord(e.key) == 13:
        uid = uidBox.value
        if uid.lower() in escapeKeys:
            exit(0)
        else:
            currentUser = codeToUser(uid)
            if currentUser:
                uidBox.cancel(focusUIN)
                uidBox.disable()

                kidBox.enable()
                kidBox.repeat(REFOCUS_TIMER, focusUIN, args = [kidBox])
                kidBox.when_key_pressed = lambda e: onTextBoxKey(e, f = kidBox)

                bigText.value = "Scan Key"
                underText.value = "Welcome, {}.".format(currentUser.name)

                app.after(USER_TIMEOUT, restart, args = ["User Timeout"])
            else:
                restart("That user doesn't exist.")
    elif f == kidBox and ord(e.key) == 13:
        kid = kidBox.value
        if kid.lower() in escapeKeys:
            exit(0)
        else:
            app.cancel(restart)

            currentKey = codeToKey(kid)
            if currentKey:
                kidBox.cancel(focusUIN)
                kidBox.disable()

                inLocker = (currentKey.loc.lower() == "locker")
                success = (checkout(currentUser, currentKey) if inLocker else checkin(currentUser, currentKey))
                if success:
                    restart("{} checked {} the {} keys.".format(currentUser.name, "out" if inLocker else "in", currentKey.toString()))
                else:
                    restart("System error, try again.")
            else:
                restart("That key doesn't exist.")

def restart (subText = ". . ."):
    global uidBox, kidBox, bigText, underText

    uidBox.value = ""
    uidBox.enable()
    uidBox.cancel(focusUIN)
    uidBox.repeat(REFOCUS_TIMER, focusUIN, args = [uidBox])
    uidBox.focus()

    kidBox.value = ""
    kidBox.cancel(focusUIN)
    kidBox.disable()

    bigText.value = "Scan Badge"
    underText.value = subText

# App
escapeKeys = "letmeout pleaseijustwanttoseemywifeandkidsagain".split(" ")
currentUser = None
currentKey = None

def codeToUser (uid = None):
    xlog("Trying to find user by RFID...")
    if uid:
        try:
            cursor.execute("select Name from user where RFID = '{}';".format(uid))
            names = []
            for n in cursor:
                names.append(n)
            if len(names) != 1:
                xlog("Ran the function, and literally got no matches for that user rfid.")
                xlog("Restarting...")
                exit(0)
                return None
            else:
                xlog("Found user: {}".format(names[0][0]))
                return User(uid, names[0][0])
        except mariadb.Error as e: # aghiulg
            xlog("Database error trying to find the user.\n{}".format(e))
            # fatalError(e)
            return None
    else:
        xlog("They didn't give me an RFID.")
        return None

def codeToKey (kid = None):
    if kid:
        try:
            cursor.execute("select KeyringID, Properties, Location from keyring where RFID = {};".format(kid))
            keys = []
            for k in cursor:
                keys.append(k)
            if len(keys) != 1:
                return None
            else:
                keys = keys[0]
                return Key(kid, keys[0], keys[1], keys[2])
        except mariadb.Error as e:
            # fatalError(e)
            return None
    else:
        return None

def checkout(user, key):
    global mdb

    log("Checking out k{} ({}) to {}.".format(key.kid, ", ".join(key.prop), user.name))
    try:
        cursor.execute("update keyring set Location = '{}' where KeyringID = {}".format(user.name, key.kid))
        mdb.commit()
        return True
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        # fatalError(e)
        mdb = connectDB()
        return False

def checkin (user, key):
    global mdb

    log("Checking in k{} ({}) from {}.".format(key.kid, ", ".join(key.prop), user.name))
    try:
        cursor.execute("update keyring set Location = 'locker' where KeyringID = {}".format(key.kid))
        mdb.commit()
        return True
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        # fatalError(e)
        mdb = connectDB()
        return False

def fatalError (e):
    log("Error: {}".format(e))
    log("Fatal error encountered, Key Locker turning off. Next user must open it by double clicking the desktop link.")
    exit()

# First Run
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bigText = Text(app, "Scan Badge", size = 40, color = "black")
    underText = Text(app, ". . .", size = 15, color = "black")

    uidBox = TextBox(app)
    uidBox.repeat(REFOCUS_TIMER, focusUIN, args = [uidBox])
    uidBox.when_key_pressed = lambda e: onTextBoxKey(e, f = uidBox)

    kidBox = TextBox(app, enabled = False)

    auditText = Text(app, size = 10, color = "black")

    app.display()
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';`

Comment: Is a single connection being used the entire time?  Or does the code disconnect?

Comment: @RickJames I've updated the post to show these variables.
A single connection is used, it attempts to reopen the connection after the error occurs, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for interactive_timeout has the default value of 28800 secs = 8 hrs, which means after 8 hrs of inactivity, the server will automatically close the connection.

I would try to increase this value and check if the disconnect still occurs.

According to PEP-249 all cursor objects become invalid as soon the connection handle becomes invalid. Since MySQL Connector/Python doesn't have an automatic reconnect option and doesn't allow to reassign a connection object to a cursor, you have to recreate your cursors before reusing it.

Answer (score 1):

On a DB error you're creating a new connection, but not a new cursor. The existing cursor is still bound to the initial connection which is now closed, that's why you keep getting errors.

Reinitialize the cursor whenever you create a new connection and you should be good.

Comment: That's a good point, I hadn't realized that. I'll edit that, and tomorrow we'll see if that was the issue,

Comment: So, when finished with an action, close both the cursor and the connection?

Comment: @XavierHorn any luck?

Comment: @kristaps Just now tried it, and no, same error persists.

Comment: @XavierHorn  This 4 year old question may be of value to your team. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228743/getting-broken-pipe-when-passing-mysql-connection-to-a-python-thread - Have you checked python.ini timeout values - if python timeout is less than mysql timeout, python may be giving up too early, by seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a locally-hosted MariaDB instance, try connecting to the DB using a Unix socket instead of TCP/IP.  In case any host-based firewall or other network weirdness with your TCP stack is interfering, you can essentially bypass it this way.

The socket for MariaDB is usually located at `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` (unless you have configured it otherwise). Verify the presence of the socket at that path (or else track down where it is),

```
> show variables like 'socket';
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                       |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| socket        | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

Then set your connection command to something like this:

```
mariadb.connect(user="Donuts", password="Candy", database="Cake", unix_socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock")
```

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html